# Ошибки компиляции в Linix

Tags: debian, gcc, linux, makefile, g++

При компиляции библиотек ace, openssl. При компиляции mysql, apache. Вбивает ошибку, к примеру:

> `make[1]: Entering directory '/root/ACE_wrappers/build/ace'.`

При конфигурации:

> `checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
> checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
> checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`

Подкиньте идейки.

Comment: > make[1]: Entering directory '/root/ACE_wrappers/build/ace'

-- это, по идее, не ошибка, просто отладочное сообщение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не вижу тут ошибок. Это обычные сообщения о прогрессе, дескать, заходим, проверяем, определяем. Архитектура `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` чуть-чуть смущает (хотя может быть это и нормально, я не помню), но это само по себе не ошибка.